# HTML5 custom paywall video player - where to store video files?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video, payment

I'm working on building an HTML5 video player that will have the support of payments. This means that the video file should not be accessible freely.

It's very straightforward when the video file is stored on my own server where the player just accesses it locally and streams it after the payment is made. Now I want to be able to provide this player for other people to be able to embed their video files on their own website and streamed through my player.

I would like to avoid having them upload their videos to my server. Is there any way for them to stream through my video player but host it on their own server? From what I understand, they can't add the url to the src of the video player because then anyone can get access to the video file directly for free by just going to the url.

Comment: if you are streaming the video in a browser then without DRM your content is not protected. you either need to look at DRM solutions (eg Ooyala, BuyDRM etc) or if obfuscation is enough use a time limited token to redirect to the real video asset (translating a code to the real video URL on the server)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal But Ooyala still requires you to use their own player if I am correct... otherwise the only other option is to upload to our servers?

Comment: if you want a full DRM solution it's a lot easier to use a player from someone who does this for a living. if you just want to obfuscate content then either store and manage the content (or a pointer to it) yourself. all depends on how secure you need it to be...

Comment: @Offbeatmammal my priority is the paywall. I want people to be able to use the player with the paywall. The paywall needs to be built into the player itself so unless these larger companies integrate my paywall into their player, I need to provide a way for people to use mine.

Comment: And even if we manage the pointer using a time limited token, that means the video file still needs to be at a public location so that my player can access it